# Is there some open source web application using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use AngularJS in my next WebApp project, before I start, have 2 questions want to ask:

1. Is AngularJS suitable for Mobile WebApp development?
2. If there is any open source application using AngularJS that I can take as references when I using AngularJS?

Comment: This is what you're looking for http://todomvc.com/

Comment: one more example could be https://www.googlesciencefair.com/en/2013/ since it is client side app so you can easily see view source

Comment: I have been working upon https://github.com/kamranahmedse/angularjs-todo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Reference application for AngularJS:

   https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app

   > The idea is to demonstrate how to write a typical, non-trivial CRUD
   >   application using AngularJS. To showcase AngularJS in its most
   >   advantageous environment we've set out to write a simplified project
   >   management tool supporting teams using the SCRUM methodology. The
   >   sample application tries to show best practices when it comes to:
   >   folders structure, using modules, testing, communicating with a REST
   >   back-end, organizing navigation, addressing security concerns
   >   (authentication / authorization).

Answer (score 4):

http://builtwith.angularjs.org/   &  filter by tag "Open Source".

---

builtwith.angularjs.org was created by AngularJS Team. It became a community standard when it comes to boasting about your project. It will be more accurate than sophisticated google query.

Comment: There exactly 4 apps with that filter

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes
2. Below are two lists of open source example Angular apps:

a) Example apps off of the Angular blog: http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/11/angularjs-example-applications.html. They range from a news reader (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/wReader-app) to a take out food application (https://github.com/IgorMinar/foodme). Many are written by those actively involved in AngularJS, so should make for decent reference material.

b) Another list of submitted apps vetted by Angular folks:
http://builtwith.angularjs.org/

Answer (score 3):

I have found this project very useful to learn Angular. https://github.com/nazar/parlmnt