# Like discourse is to Ember.js, what are some big open source project written rails + angularjs?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ember.js

Discourse is a open source project written in rails and Ember.js so its a really good resource in case someone is looking to learn rails or Ember.js.

I am wondering are there are any fairly large open source projects written in angularjs and rails which are popular & under active development?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call Discourse a good resource for learning Rails. I can't comment on the ember.js side of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Built with Angular JS](http://builtwith.angularjs.org/) and search the open-source tag, people keep adding new open source projects there they are using angular

A resource that is a book is [Riding the Rails with Angular JS](https://leanpub.com/angularjs-rails)

And there is a railscasts on Angular JS and rails [Railscast-405-AngularJS](http://railscasts.com/episodes/405-angularjs)

Also. another SO question about angular in general [Is there some open source web application using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416135/is-there-some-open-source-web-application-using-angularjs)